# Google Cloud CDN - Can I choose distributions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-cdn

AWS allows users to choose CDN(CloudFront) distributions and I did find a documentation about it on their site.
However, on Google  Cloud  Platform(GCP), I did not find anything saying that users can choose which distributions they like.
I currently don't have a GCP account so I cannot test it myself due to some registration issue. So can anyone please tell me, is it possible to choose distributions? Since I'd like to exclude certain area while using.

Comment: It's not clear which of two possible features you are looking to see whether the GCP CDN supports... it may be [price class](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PriceClass.html) which allows you to configure CloudFront to use only edges within certain geographically-based cost ranges, or [geo-restriction/geo-blocking](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/georestrictions.html), which allows you to restrict the approximate geographic areas from which your content can be accessed.  I suspect it is the latter, but please clarify.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, the latter is what I meant. But my concern is that does Google Cloud CDN have price classs and geo-restriction/geo-blocking like AWS does?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no geoblocking option in GCP. But there is [price](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/pricing#cache_egress_pricing_table) differentiation based in destination.